# Make barWidth fix in barchart

Tags: ios-charts

I am using Charts [library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I want to keep chart max width fix. I didn't find any way to restrict to some width.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to find the problem in my code. I was adding long value for X, which was creating the problem. I corrected **the X value** and everything is perfect :)

```
BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(x_Value), y: Double(y_Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to make sure the width of a bar is never more than a certain proportion of the screen width. For example setting the setVisibleXRangeMinimum to 10 means each bar will be around 1/10 of the screen width

```
barChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(10.0)
```

You can also set the maximum:

```
barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10.0)
```

Comment: Let me try that. I was thinking ChartBar will have some method to hard fix it. I will look into it and lets see if it solve my purpose.

Comment: But why would you want to have the width fixed? That would make each bar look differently when using different screen sizes. Having the width proportional makes the graph look the same on all screen sizes.

Comment: I am sharing my code and end result as well for chart configuration. Still not getting the desired result.

        chartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0
        chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
        chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
                
        let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        xAxis.labelCount = dataCount
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.granularity = 0.2
        
        let leftAxisFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucuSP.png

Comment: Finally, I am able to find the problem in my code. I was adding long value for X, which was creating the problem. BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(x_Value), y: Double(y_Value))